# Дублирование запросов

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

Запускаю `uvicorn` с `fastAPI`.

```
PYTHONPATH=. main:app --workers=2 --port=8080 --host=0.0.0.0
```

Следующий пример:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Lock
import fastapi


app = fastapi.FastAPI()
lock = Lock()


import os
p = os.getpid()
print('start', p)


@app.get('/health', status_code=204)
async def health():
    lock.acquire()
    print(p)
    time.sleep(5)
    lock.release()
    return
```

Захожу в браузер. Открываю 3 вкладки и последовательно, делаю 3 запроса так, чтобы уложиться в таймаут 5 секунд. В консоли вижу:

```
PYTHONPATH=. main:app --workers=2 --port=8080 --host=0.0.0.0
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started parent process [8799]
start 8802
INFO:     Started server process [8802]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
start 8801
INFO:     Started server process [8801]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
8801
INFO:     127.0.0.1:57484 - "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 204 No Content
8802
8801
INFO:     127.0.0.1:57488 - "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 204 No Content
INFO:     127.0.0.1:57494 - "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 204 No Content
8802
INFO:     127.0.0.1:57502 - "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 204 No Content
8801
INFO:     127.0.0.1:57510 - "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 204 No Content
```

Видно, что прошло, 5 запросов. Почему так происходит? Почему 5 вместо 3х. Если я сделаю 2 запроса, то увижу 3 вывода вместо 2х.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная проблема не воспроизводится, если воспользоваться `curl` и сделать 3 одновременных запроса:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/health
```

Comment: Думаете, браузер дублирует запросы?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Как ещё это объяснить?

Comment: попробуй это `for n in {1..5}; do curl http://localhost:8000/health & ; done`

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci так оно друг за другом будет выполняться, а не в параллель.

Comment: Нет, они будут работать параллельно `[1] 79239
[2] 79240
[3] 79241
[4] 79242
[5] 79243
[1]   Done  curl http://localhost:8000/health
[2]   Done  curl http://localhost:8000/health
[3]   Done  curl http://localhost:8000/health
[4]   Done  curl http://localhost:8000/health
[5]   Done  curl http://localhost:8000/health
`

Comment: В основном одиночный оператор амперсанда работает асинхронно, потому что он сообщает приведенной выше команде работать в фоновом режиме. (Кстати, извините, если я делаю языковые ошибки, я перевожу это
)

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci не страшно. Как Вы попали на русский SO?

Comment: @hedgehogues, всякий раз, когда
 новый вопрос, опубликованный с тегом fastapi, он отправляет мне электронное письмо, да звучит немного страшновато :)